# Unit Testing Java 8 Predicates

Tags: unit-testing, java-8, predicate

I have a Java 8 Predicate like this. How do I write unit test for this

```
 Predicate<DTO> isDone = (dtO) ->
                (!dto.isFinished() &&
                !dto.isCompleted());
```

Thanks

Comment: Start by writing **in words** a description of different things to test. You should include a specific input and expected output in your description.

Answer (score 4):

I would test it like that:

```
private final Predicate<DTO> isDone = (dto) ->
        (!dto.isFinished() && !dto.isCompleted());

@Test
public void a() throws Exception {
    // given
    DTO dto = new DTO(true, true);

    // when
    boolean result = isDone.test(dto);

    // then
    assertThat(result).isFalse();
}

@Test
public void s() throws Exception {
    // given
    DTO dto = new DTO(true, false);

    // when
    boolean result = isDone.test(dto);

    // then
    assertThat(result).isFalse();
}

@Test
public void d() throws Exception {
    // given
    DTO dto = new DTO(false, true);

    // when
    boolean result = isDone.test(dto);

    // then
    assertThat(result).isFalse();
}

@Test
public void f() throws Exception {
    // given
    DTO dto = new DTO(false, false);

    // when
    boolean result = isDone.test(dto);

    // then
    assertThat(result).isTrue();
}

@AllArgsConstructor
public static class DTO {
    private final boolean isFinished;
    private final boolean isCompleted;

    public boolean isFinished() {
        return isFinished;
    }

    public boolean isCompleted() {
        return isCompleted;
    }
}
```

Instead of `a`, `s`, and `f` name the tests properly like: `should_be_done_when_it_is_both_finished_and_completed`.

I suppose `DTO` is just a value object so I'd rather create real instance instead of using mock.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a reference to the predicate (as it seems in your example) then I see no issues. Here is simple example with Mockito/JUnit:

```
@Mock
private DTO mockDTO;

@Test
public void testIsDone_Finished_NotComplete()
{
    when(mockDTO.isFinished()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mockDTO.isCompleted()).thenReturn(false);

    boolean expected = false;
    boolean actual = isDone.test(mockDTO);

    Assert.assertEquals(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: I have a private predicate in my resource class, my test class is not able to access it. How should I test that?

Comment: private boolean hasNewCourseInfo(Course course) {

  Predicate<Incidents> dateofPredicate = e -> e.getDateofCreation().isAfter(course.getcourseStatus().getDateofcreation());
  return course.getIncidents().stream().anyMatch(dateofPredicate );
 }